# How to add an Input into an option of a dropdown list

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a dropdown list of technology with a mat-select element and I would like to add for each option an input to specify the technology's version.

My dropdown list :

Close : [image: closed dropdown]
Open : [image: opened dropdown]

The problem is that when I click in the input to write the version, it selects the option without editing the input.

[image: where I clicked]

Here is my code :

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
   <mat-label>Choisissez les technologies parmi cette liste</mat-label>
   <mat-select formControlName="listeTechnologies" multiple> 
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of listeDeroulanteTechnologies" [value]="item.code1">
         {{ item.valeur1}} 
         <input type="text" placeholder="Version"/>
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select> 
</mat-form-field>
```

Stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lednqy?file=src/app/app.component.html

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You could use 
[stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)
 to make one.

Comment: @MikeS. thank you, I added a stackblitz link.

Comment: Thank you for the stackblitz! I had a quick look and found out that the `input` elements' focus event is overwritten by the `mat-option`. You can arrange the `mat-option` and `input` like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-biuoxq?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: (I can post this as an answer when the question is reopened, SO is sadly kinda slow on this)

Comment: @MikeS. you can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the exemple [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-biuoxq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) I've found the solution :

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
   <mat-label>Choisissez les technologies parmi cette liste</mat-label>
   <mat-select formControlName="listeTechnologies" multiple> 
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listeDeroulanteTechnologies ; let i = index" class="containerTechnologie" formArrayName="listeVersion">
         <mat-option class="optionTechnologie" [value]="item.code1">{{ item.valeur1}}</mat-option>
         <mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="versionTechnologie">
            <input placeholder="Version {{item.valeur1}}" matInput [formControlName]="i"/>
         </mat-form-field> <br/>
      </ng-container>
   </mat-select> 
</mat-form-field>
```

CSS Classes :

```css
.containerTechnologie{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.optionTechnologie{
    display:inline-flex;
    width:100%;
}

.versionTechnologie{
    width:25%;
    position:absolute;
    right:35%;
    margin-top:-15px;
}
```

Result :
[image: Dropdownlist]